# Does the full node software come with DDoS protection?

Tags: iri-node, ddos

I am interested in running my own node, but does the software offer DDoS protection in any way? Should I do this at the network layer? What best practices are common here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no build in DDoS protection.

In my opinion, you have two options:

1. External Software like https://github.com/jgmdev/ddos-deflate
2. You could whitelist your neighbours with iptables.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I hope that one day the node software becomes a "one click" thing where it just works and does everything for you without having to worry about DDoS, finding neighbours, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure as IOTA grows and more devs become interested, there will be lots of community driven projects like that.

Comment: If you go whitelist there's no access point for wallets....